# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g

trying to return data using `OracleDataReader`, getting

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object " at the line "odr = 
ocmd.ExecuteReader();",
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing / done wrong?

thanks

T

```
           OracleConnection cn = null;
            OracleDataReader odr = null;
            OracleCommand ocmd = null;

            String con1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HousingDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            cn = new OracleConnection(con1);
            cn.Open();

            string mysql = "SELECT stuff from tables";
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(mysql, cn);
            odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
            Label2.Text = "connection success";

            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            while (odr.Read()) 
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(odr["TCY_CORRESPOND_NAME"].ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared ocmd as null, but then you created another OracleCommand object as cmd. ocmd was never instantiated.

This part is wrong:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(mysql, cn); 
odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
```

It should be:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(mysql, cn); 
odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 2):

`ocmd` and `cmd` are two different variables.

Comment: the perils of cut n paste! thanks both of you, never even noticed that

Answer (score 1):

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(mysql, cn);
```

should be

```
OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand(mysql, cn);
```